# getch() not responding to stop loop

Tags: c++, linux, loops, getch

Assume that ncurses header is there and that my `random_number_generator()` method is working. I am trying to exit the loop by hitting 'a' (eventually I want to exit by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>).

My code continues to print random numbers every second as intended. I want it to exit if either condition is met:

1. It will exit if the random number is a multiple of the divisor.
2. It will exit if I use `getch()`. I think this should work but it is not exiting when I hit <kbd>a</kbd>.

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int lowest = atoi(argv[1]);
     int highest = atoi(argv[2]);
     int divisor = atoi(argv[3]);

     int random_number;
     srand((unsigned)time(0));

     int c;
     do
     {
       random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
       cout << random_number << endl;
       sleep(1);
     } while(random_number % divisor != 0 || (c=getch())!=49);

     return 0;
   }
   ```

**Edit:**

I tried changing the condition to && instead but getch still does not let it exit:

Random number outputs range 1-10:

```
4
a3    <-hit a
aaa4  <-hit a many times
5     <-exits
```

Comment: because of  Short-Circuit  behavior of `||`

Answer (score 2):

Because of [Short-Circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior of logical or operator `||` if first expression true second doesn't execute.

```
    random_number % divisor != 0  ||  (c=getch())!=49
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^
       True                           not get executes
```

Comment: I tried using && but it outputs as shown in my edits above. It exits when a multiple is found but not when I hit 'a'.

Comment: @MarcoLau because && also supports  Short-Circuit

Comment: @MarcoLau do you want `getch()` always called ?

Comment: Looking at the big picture, I want the loop to exit if a multiple is found or if I hit 'a', although eventually I want to exit by hitting 'Ctrl-E'.

Comment: @MarcoLau Not sure, try  this `(c = getch())! = 49 && (random_number % divisor != 0);`

Comment: @MarcoLau `ctrl + E` ?  Is `49` ?

Comment: That is the current condition I have now. I am starting to think I am missing a minor detail regarding getch(). This condition produces similar results I have provided in the edit.

Comment: `ctrl + e` is 5. I am trying to keep things simple at the moment and use a, which is 49. Multiple keystrokes might cause complications.

Comment: On C++, would you use ncurses of getch() to handle such keystrokes or are there other tools that can resolve this problem?

Comment: @MarcoLau I will not write `(c=getch())!=49` in while condition

Comment: I may agree with you on that but I am at a lost as to where I should implement this option. I wrapping the do-while with a while loop using the '(c=getch())!=49' condition. It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Because `random_number % divisor != 0` is true thats why it does't care whatever you enter

use `&&` instead

Comment: I tried using && but it still prints without exiting. Please refer to edit of original post.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a condition, make sure that all parts are behaving as expected.

To be more clear you should better use:

```
do
    {
        random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
        cout << random_number << endl;
        sleep(1);
    } while(random_number % divisor != 0 && (c=getch())!='a');
```

Now if you enter 'a', the second condition is is false, and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop has an OR operator (||) with two conditions, evaluation is performed from left to right in this case. There are two situations where the condition can be true,  one is if the random_number % divisor == 0 , the other is  c=getch() == 49 , if either of theses conditions is true then loop will terminate, otherwise it will perform its next iteration.

Since the condition evaluation is performed from left to right, so if the first condition inside the while() is true, the next iteration is performed, so whenever the random_number % divisor == 0 then next iteration will be performed.

Solution: put the c=getch() != 49 on the left side, make it the first condition and put the random_number % divisor !=0 on the right side, make it the second condition from left to right.

Comment: No, this does not work. I tried it and it still,as expected, prints without exiting. I believe all conditions are evaluated first and determined true or false as a whole.

Comment: //try this

do
{
    random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
    cout << random_number << endl;
    sleep(1);
    char c=getch();
} while(random_number % divisor != 0 && c != 'a');

Comment: I tried moving the variables around including this. None worked. There is a flaw in your code because the initialization is inside the do-while loop. The while condition outside therefore has no source to read 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

because at any given input atleast on condition is satisfied and or(||) continues the loop.USe and(&&) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your operation `|| to &&`  and also make `c=getch()!=49` first control.  You can see example below;

```
int lowest = atoi(argv[1]);
int highest = atoi(argv[2]);
int divisor = atoi(argv[3]);

int random_number;
srand((unsigned)time(0));

int c;
do
{
    random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
    cout << random_number << endl;
    sleep(1);
} while((c=getch())!=49 && random_number % divisor != 0);

return 0;
```

Comment: My code is in this state at the moment. I believe it is the most sensible but it still doesn't work. My code still exits the loop when a multiple is found but not when I hit 'a'.

Comment: Make your second control in paranthesis like ;

(random_number % divisor != 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
    do
        {
            random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
            cout << random_number << endl;

            if(random_number % divisor == 0)
            break;
            else if((c=getchar())=='a')
            break;
            else;

            sleep(1);

        } while(1);
```

Comment: Interesting. It still doesn't work. Perhaps I am missing a minor detail of using getch().

Comment: In my case, the else if is waiting for my input. Nothing happens after printing the first random number. It continues to print after I hit 'a'. Again, exits when a multiple is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int lowest = atoi(argv[1]);
  int highest = atoi(argv[2]);
  int divisor = atoi(argv[3]);

  int random_number;
  srand((unsigned)time(0));

  char c;
  do
  {
    random_number = random_number_generator(lowest, highest);
    printf("%d\n",random_number);
     if(random_number % divisor == 0)
     break;
     else if(kbhit()){
            c = getch();
            if(c=='a')
            break;
     }
     else;
    sleep(1);
  } while(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is not available for Linux. Are you using a windows machine? I will give this a shot and see the results.

Comment: ya i am using windows, it will go on executing until key 'a' is pressed or randomnumber = 0

Comment: kbhit is not available on linux.

Comment: I tried implementing the header file and used `#include "kbhit.h"`. I have not been able to run it because of a compile error `main.cpp:50:20: error: ‘kbhit’ was not declared in this scope
` I tried doing this with your code first. I am still working on finding a way to fix this but I think this is a dead end.

Comment: Include both kbhit.h and kbhit.c

Comment: `main.cpp:7:21: fatal error: kbhit.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`
I tried using kbhit.cpp but it produced the same result.

Comment: if your file is cpp file then use source code at bottom from the link.
Make sure both the files are in same directory

Comment: I did those. The files are also in the same directory. This is what's confusing me. I restarted my IDE to see if that helps but to no avail.